# AG Grid - Look for columns that are editable

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In my angular project I use ag-grid tables. In one of them I have a column that is editable, however it looks just like all the other columns. Only after double clicking into a cell one can see that it is editable. How can I make the cells look like they are editable?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your cell looks the same as all of the others until you double-click on it is that the editor is not created until you double-click on it (start editing).

You can change the look of the cells by specifying a "cellClass" in the column definition, and then applying css for that class.

See the documentation at https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/#cell-class